# OpenCV strip sRGB profile when imdecode image Python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, libpng, srgb

I am reading in images which I fetch from the internet and then immediately read into OpenCV in python as below:

```
# read in image as bytes from page
image = page.raw_stream.read()
frame = cv2.imdecode(np.asarray(bytearray(image)), 0)
```

and I am getting the libpng warning:

```
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
```

How can I strip the sRGB profile before imread? People are suggesting to do it via imagemagick on the png files before reading them but this is not possible for me. Is there no way to do this in python directly?

EDIT:

I am unable to get the code in the answer below to fix my problem, if I run it with the file at https://uploadfiles.io/m1w2l and use the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

with open('data/47.png', 'rb') as test:
   image = np.asarray(bytearray(test.read()), dtype="uint8")
   image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

I get the same warning

Comment: Can you download one of these files on disk and then read with `cv2.imread`? Also post a link to one of these files.

Comment: I was doing that before but it significantly slowed down the code having to save and read from a file with the volume of images I was processing, here is one of the files: https://imgur.com/a/3w21Mrh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `urllib`:

```
import cv2
import urllib

resp = urllib.request.urlopen('https://i.imgur.com/QMPkIkZ.png')
image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

Using `skimage`:

```
import cv2
from skimage import io

image = io.imread('https://i.imgur.com/QMPkIkZ.png')
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2BGRA)
```

If you get a weird display using OpenCV `cv2.imshow`, keep in mind that OpenCV does not display alpha channels.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I think however that imgur actually fixes the sRGB on their server. Could you please use this file to test and the code that I have updated the question with: https://uploadfiles.io/m1w2l thanks!