# Unable to load image

Tags: python, image

I cannot change an image from web to an array.

Can anyone help?

Thank you very much.

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import requests
import numpy as np

url =r'https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1xrKyFZAIIR_XVhlhYGHlfLvIr5vQ5EnW'
img = Image.open(BytesIO(requests.get(url).content))
arr = np.array(img, dtype = np.uint8)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#78>", line 1, in <module>
    arr = np.array(img, dtype = np.uint8)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'JpegImageFile'
```

Comment: Download the image and save it in .jpg format. Try 'imread' command from Scipy library.

Comment: Do you have an error ? which one ? I guess it depends on the image format

Comment: This is really weird... calling `np.array(img, dtype = np.uint8)` throws a ValueError the first time, but if you try it again it works...

Comment: Do you want to convert the raw bytes of the image file, or the decoded image data (RGB values) to an array?

Comment: Let @zindarod help... https://stackoverflow.com/a/50530022/2836621

Comment: @spectre     I have lots of images to process. Downloading them will take a long time

Comment: @user801247    The error has been added in the question

Comment: @Aran-Fey Yes, do you know why?

Comment: @mkrieger I want to get the size of the image

Comment: @Mark Thank you for your help. What is the problem of my original code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the help of Mark. The solution to this problem is:

```
import cv2
import requests
import numpy as np

url =r'https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1xrKyFZAIIR_XVhlhYGHlfLvIr5vQ5EnW'
resp = requests.get(url).content
image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp), dtype="uint8")
arr = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```